# Why is there a democratic-primary tag with 39 questions but until just now no republican-primary tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why is there a [democratic-primary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/democratic-primary) tag with 39 questions but until just now<sup>1</sup> no [republican-primary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republican-primary) tag? I'd created the latter for [How did Alaska "change its primary system recently" and was it "to dilute the possibility of a conservative or Trump-inspired challenger"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/62878/16047)

I just think that the asymmetry in usage is curious, and questions about how the site works and features are used belong here in meta.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's since been removed because it turns out that the changes made as outlined in the answer there affected the primaries *both parties*.

Comment: I think it's probably because there was a heated and complex democratic primary in 2019-2020, while the last Republican primary (for president) was way back in 2016 and no one made it then

Answer (score 17):

If you look at the question under the [democratic-primary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/democratic-primary) tag and sort by date, then you will notice that most of the questions were asked in 2019 and 2020. During that time the Republicans had an incumbent President, so the Republican primaries in that election period were mostly a formality. Which explains why there was little interest in that topic.

I am only counting 6 questions about the 2016 primaries, where both the Democrats and the Republicans had to find a new presidential candidate to nominate. There were actually at least 8 questions about the Republican primaries during that timeframe, but [those were tagged as both republican-party and primaries](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republican-party+primaries).

Answer (score 5):

Another factor is the different dynamic of the 2016 Democratic primary vs the 2016 Republican Primary.

Once it became clear the Hilary Clinton would win the Democratic nomination, there was a *lot* of discussion from Sanders supporters (who skew young and online-savvy) about how Sanders still win, and how the mechanism of the Democratic primary was unfair. This led to interest in, and questions about, the rules and bylaws of the Democratic party primary.

Once Donald Trump pulled ahead in the primary, there was a similar group of anti-Trump Republicans (the so-called "never Trumpers") who attempted to stop him from  becoming the Republican nominee. These people, on the other hand, skewed older, didn't have the social media presence of the pro-Trump crowd, and focused more on trying to persuade Republican voters and delegates than on technical tricks to affect the outcome. Hence, there was less interest in the rules and by-laws of the Republican primary, which would be the intended purpose of a [republican-primary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republican-primary) tag.